# Node.js app crashes whenever the remote host closes socket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Here is the source code of the server socket :

```
const server = net.createServer(client => {
   // 'connection' listener.
   let processing = false;

   client.setTimeout(config.socket.timeout);
   client.on('data', data => {
      const batches = data.toString().split(',');

      if (!processing && batches && batches.length) {
         processing = true;

         processBatch(batches, error => {
            const status = error ? 'ERR' : 'SUCC';

            logger.verbose('... Ended with status : ' + status);

            client.write(status, () => client.end());
         });
      }
   });
   client.on('timeout', () => {
     logger.warn('Client socket did time out');
     client.end();
   });

   //client.on('end', () => {});
});
server.on('error', error => {
   logger.info('Socket error');
   logger.error('Error: ', error);
});
server.listen(config.socket.port, () => {
   console.log('*** Socket listening on port', config.socket.port);
});
```

The client would connect, send it's data, and then remotely close the connection, which makes the server error handler be fired with, logging the message :

```
Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:441:14)
    at file:///home/thermo/bwkl/src/service.js:191:20
    at file:///home/thermo/bwkl/src/service.js:123:13 {
 code: 'EPIPE'
}
```

How can this be prevented, and gracefully close the client socket when the remote host prematurely ended the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `server` error handler does not catch the connection error because the error event is emitted by the `client`.

You should define a listener for `error` event on the `client` instance in order to handle the error in question:

```
client.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Connection error:', err.message);
});
```

This will prevent the Node.js process from crash. You can handle the error as desired inside the listener.

Comment: Yes, it seems like I need the `client.on('end', () => {})` as well, and both prevent the process from crashing.